# Can I listen music from USB-C port by using USB-C/Jack adapter trough MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-music, spotify

As mentioned in heading, can I listen to music through my headphones by using USB-C with `jack adapter` on Macbook PRO??

[https://www.amazon.com/Headphone-CONMDEX-Converter-Compatible-Essential/dp/B07DXP213B/ref=sr_1_14?ie=UTF8&qid=1546864073&sr=8-14&keywords=usb-c+jack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07DXP213B)

Comment: Nice edits +1 for the detail! Welcome to Ask Different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in general these USB to audio adapters work well with the MacBook Pro. I haven't tried the specific one you're linking, but I have tried others that worked without problems - no need to install drivers for example.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is go to Sound prefernces and change the output to USB [image: Sound Preferences]